# If joint probabilities equal mean their distributions are equal?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. $N(0, 1)$, and let $S$ be a random sign (1 or -1, with equal probabilities) independent of $(X, Y)$.

\begin{align*}
P((SX,SY)∈B)&=P((X,Y)∈B,S=1)+P((−X,−Y)∈B,S=−1) \\
&= P((X,Y)∈B)P(S=1)+P((−X,−Y)∈B)P(S=−1)\\
&= 0.5*P((X,Y)∈B) + 0.5*P((−X,−Y)∈B)\\
&= P((X,Y)∈B)
\end{align*}

How can we say that $(SX, SY)$ is multivariate normal?

Comment: The joint density function for $SX$ and $SY$ stays the same for each choice of $S$, so the joint density function is unchanged from the joint density of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg If $P((SX, SY) \in B) = P((X,Y)\in B)$, does it mean joint pdf are necessarily equal?

Comment: Yes, of course! By the very definition of joint distribution.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I can see it intuitively. However, is it a general result or is it because the densities are continuous so that derivative of joint CDF gives joint PDF.

Comment: The joint distribution of $(SX,SY)$ is that of $(X,Y)$, from which the result follows. That $X$ is a continuous random variable is irrelevant.